# I have the Firebase Auth ID, how do I use it in a db list?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have used

```
fAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
  if (user) { this.userId = user.uid }
});
```

however, I am now trying to search within userProfile via the id to get the points value.

```
getTotalPoints(){
  this.db.list('/userProfile/' + this.userId).valueChanges().subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
      this.pointsValue = data;
    }
  )
}
```

I get the error

> Runtime Error
>
> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/userProfile/[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]" Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/userProfile/[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]" at Object.exports.validatePathString

Sorry if the answered is simple very new to this.

Here's the
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bqTJ.jpg)

Full page code

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-    angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
})

export class DashboardPage {

  pointsValue: {}

  userId = {}

  tasks:Array<any> = [];


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public db: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {


    afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
      if (user) { this.userId = user.uid }
    });

    this.getTotalPoints()

     this.tasks = [
      { 
      name: 'Clean bedroom', 
      status: '100' 
      },
      { 
      name: 'Empty dishwasher', 
      status: '100' 
      },
      { 
      name: 'Take dog for a walk', 
      status: '100' 
      },
    ];

  }

  checkUser() {
    console.log(this.userId);
  }

  getTotalPoints(){
    this.db.list('/userProfile/' + this.userId).valueChanges().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        this.pointsValue = data;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of this? `console.log(this.userId);`

Comment: it returns the correct uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the error

> First argument was an invalid path = "/userProfile/[object Object]"

```
userId = {} //is an object, where it should be a non-object data type
```

And in your code

```
 //You're doing a async method
 afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
      if (user) { this.userId = user.uid }
    });
 /*After that you called your method, which caused userId 
 to be an object since you initialized it as an empty object */
 this.getTotalPoints()
```

For better implementation do it this way

```
//Set userId as null
userId: any = null
```

Make this function have a parameter of userId

```
 getTotalPoints(id: any){
    this.db.list('/userProfile/' + id).valueChanges().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        this.pointsValue = data;
      }
    )
  }
```

then in the subscription call do it this way

```
afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
      if (user) { 
          this.userId = user.uid 
          this.getTotalPoints(this.userId);
       }
    });
```

Comment: that worked, thank you. How would I just pull through the points value?

Comment: Hi @NathanMillward what do you mean by pulling through the points value?

Comment: <h1 padding=10px *ngFor="let value of pointsValue"> 
         {{ value }} 
</h1>
displays email, username and points. How would I just display points? I tried value.points

Comment: You can ask this for another question, but well do it like this `<h1 padding=10px *ngFor="let value of pointsValue"> {{ value.points }} </h1>`

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You use object instead of list if you want to get data of Firebase Object

```
getTotalPoints(){
this.db.object('/userProfile/' + this.userId).valueChanges().subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    this.pointsValue = data;
  }
)
```

More info in the AngularFire2 doc: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md